# How to Get a Whiter Background when Taking Photos Against An Off White Wall?

Tags: white-balance, point-and-shoot, background, powershot

[image]I am trying to take a photo of a banner against an off white wall.  Is there a way to get a pure white background and the banner colors not be overexposed?  I am using a point a point and shoot camera on auto settings.  Right now, the picture looks a little/blueish.

Comment: Bluish is common color temperature (white ballance) adjustment.  (Or a reference to the end of *Yellow Submarine*.)   Why can't you move the banner or slide a paper behind it?  Paper with a color not found in the subject would be easier than white when the brightness varies so much.

Answer (score 1):

ideally you should light the background and the banner separately. This might be quite hard to achieve this look if you are using auto mode though. Does your camera have a manual mode by any chance?

Leon

Comment: oh ok.  And yes, it does have a manual mode.

Comment: I think you need a bit more detail there... Manual mode is all well and good, but your basic suggestion means image compositing and you should probably explain that.

Comment: Do you have any editing software? I made a video on this exact subject on my youtube channel but if you don't have any editing software it might be worth having a look at this free software http://www.gimp.org/downloads/

Comment: Hi Joanne, lighting the subject and the background would be taken in one shot so no compositing would be necessary. I suggested using manual mode so you can take full control of the camera and make the exposure as bright as you need for the look you want.

Comment: @Leon -- Most people using P&S probably don't have appropriate lighting gear for that purpose, so I took that as light for the background (or overexpose) and then light for the banner and merge after. (As an aside, use the "@" before the name and you will notify the person)

Comment: I have Photoshop and I do have a few cowboy continous lights that I could use.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible without manipulating the results in an editing program.

Comment: While true, the _how_ you would do this is probably a more real and complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

With the banner against the wall, rather than separated from it, you have to make the subject look right and fix the background in PS.  Use a tripod and take a series of bracketed exposures.  Tools for HDR/tone mapping might make quick work of the resulting stack, or IAC the overexposed version is good for making the mask.

I have a similar issue with scanning old magazine pages: I use color-match selection and delete the off-white paper leaving only the ink.  Making the wall evenly lit would be the most helpful there.